# How to Clear or Delete cookie in Production Mode?

Tags: cookies, e-commerce, mern, production

I am unable to delte or clear my cookie "token" when I am running the website in Production mode, nut in Development mode it works fine.
While logging in my website in Production mode, I find that the cookie "token" sets in properly, (Set-Cookie is visible in Response Headers), but when I logout I dont see Set-Cookie in response headers. I unable to perform any action action on the existing cookie, which means my client is unable to log out till the cookie expires.

I have tried many commands from different websites but nothing helps